# Angular Avoid Unnecessary Dependency Injection

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm not building traditional SPA, instead pages are generate server-side. But I do have an angular app that I import into all my pages on my site.  For example:

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ui.bootstrap', 'ngTable','textAngular']);
```

Quite a simple question but I've failed to ask Google the right question(s) to find an answer.  Not all my pages require textAngular for example, yet my Angular app will not load unless I import this script on to every page.  What is the best practice to avoid this problem?

Comment: by "page" do you mean Angular route or an actual page that loads from your server? Angular creates single page apps so you should have one page that does require all of your dependencies. Angular will take care of lazily loading up the module when it is needed.

Comment: Good point.  Unfortunately I'm not building SPA.  I'm populating templates from server-side and directing to separate pages at this point.

Comment: ah I see. you could probably do something like create a separate module for each page then and only load in what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to load the script in every page. Normally Angular is used in the context of a SPA web app (Single Page Application). That means you only have one page (index.html) and you use routing to change the current view. You should reference the script in the index.html if some module in your application needs this feature.

If you are using server generated pages (With ASP .NET, PHP, etc.) you can add script references for every page but is not the usual way to work with Angular. (It is called mini spa application). If this is your scenario you only have to reference the script for textAngular (and define the dependency in the module declaration) on the pages that you need to use it.

Comment: Should have specified not building a SPA. Pages are generated server-side unfortunately. You mentioned "...you only have to reference the script for textAngular (and define the dependency in the module declaration) on the pages that you need to use it.", this causes a crash for me like the following: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.24/$injector/modulerr?p0=htsApp&p1=Error%3A…20c%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A170)

Comment: Do you have an example of some server page that textAngular is not needed? You aren't including script reference and in the app module declaration you aren't including  textAngular dependency, are you?